# Android 3.0 "holographic" theme borders

Tags: android, imageview, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am trying to draw and animate several ImageView items on a screen and I would like to have the images display the blue borders used in other Honeycomb apps (examples of borders here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UPSBctbYc9Q @ 1:10).

I've seen hacks/workarounds for older versions of Android using a background image, but I was hoping to avoid that.  Can anyone help me to add such borders?

Thanks

Comment: I looked at 1min10sec can't see what your talking about. A screen shot would be much clearer than a video.

Comment: As requested, here's an image (taken from the video):
http://img135.imageshack.us/i/borders.png/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest just creating a custom view using `FrameLayout` as its base to layer up the background/border, and then the ImageView on top using an appropriate padding value such that the border remains visible.

Comment: Is there anything in honeycomb to get the exact same look (perhaps some built-in theme stuff), or do I need to just try to copy their style as best as I can?

Comment: The 3D carousel used in the YouTube app is closed-source (for the moment, anyway) so for now you'll just have to emulate it as best you can. I've heard they plan to open-source that component at some point in time as a Renderscript example, but can't count on that.